# Python quiz not writing to txt file

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple arithmetic quiz. Once the user has completed the quiz, I want to write their name and score to a text file. However, if they have already completed the quiz, then their new score should be appended on the same line as their previous score is on.
Currently the text file contains:
 `Raju,Joyal : 10`
However, when completing the test under the same surname, the new score is not appended to this line, and when completing the test under a different surname no new line is written to the text file at all.
This is my code:

```
rewrite = False
flag = True
while flag == True:
    try:

        # opening src in a+ mode will allow me to read and append to file
        with open("Class {0} data.txt".format(classNo),"a+") as src:

            # list containing all data from file, one line is one item in list
            data = src.readlines()

            for ind,line in enumerate(data):

                if surname.lower() in line.lower():
                    # overwrite the relevant item in data with the updated score
                    data[ind] = "{0} {1}\n".format(line.rstrip(), ", ",score)
                    rewrite = True

                else:
                    src.write("{0},{1} : {2}{3} ".format(surname, firstName, score,"\n"))


        if rewrite == True:

            # reopen src in write mode and overwrite all the records with the items in data
            with open("Class {} data.txt".format(classNo),"w") as src2: 
                src2.writelines(data)

        flag = False

    except IOError:
        errorHandle("Data file not found. Please ensure data files are the in same folder as the program")
```

Comment: Just a pointer: It sounds like you want a database.

Comment: Using a database sounds like it would be overkill.

Comment: @keyser this was just a small project, didn't want to go to advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're opening the file but, because you're in "append" mode (`a+`) your read/write pointer is positioned at the *end* of the file.  So when you say `readlines()` you get nothing: even if the file is not empty, there are no *more* lines past where you currently are.   As a result, your `for` loop is iterating over a list of length 0,  so the code never runs.

You should read up on working with files (look for the keywords `seek` and `tell`).

Note that even if you're positioned in the right place in the middle of the file, overwriting what's already there in an existing file will  not be a good way to go:  if the data you want to write are a different number of bytes from what you want to overwrite, you'll get problems.  Instead you'll probably want to open one copy of the file for reading and create a new one to write to.  When they're both finished and closed, move the newer file to replace the older one.

Finally note that `if surname.lower() in line.lower()`  is not watertight logic.   What happens if your file has the entry `Raju,Joyal: 10` and someone else has the surname "Joy" ?

Comment: aah, so opening in r+ mode is the way to go so that it is not neccessary to seek()

Comment: No I just realised that r+ wouldn't be effective as it would overwrite

Comment: Here's a completely different idea:  store, access and manipulate your data in a `dict` in memory.  Let's say `d={'joyal,raju':10}`  To read that `dict` from disk or save it to disk, you have various options, but the quickest one is the `pickle` module. You could also save it in more human-readable format using `open('output.txt', 'wt').write( str(d) )`.  To read it, you could say `s=open('output.txt', 'rt').read()` and then evaluate the result with `exec( 'd = ' + s )`  (beware, that last statement is *terrible* practice from the security point of view—but maybe OK for a "small project"...).

Answer (score 0):

This is from my own project but I don't know if it helps:

```
file=open("Mathematics Test Results (v2.5).txt","a")
file.write("Name: "+name+", Score: "+str(score)+", Class: "+cls+"."+"\n")
file.close()
```